# The code is printing none instead of different permutations

Tags: python, return, permutation

The program here is in python and it is meant to print different permutations of the input.
For example
input : `[1,2,3]`

output : `[1,2,3],[1,3,2],[2,1,3],[2,3,1],[3,1,2],[3,2,1]`

The code

```
def swap(a,b):
    temp=a
    a=b
    b=temp
    return a,b
def permut(z,l,n):
    if l==n:
        return (z)
    else:
        for i in range(l,n):
            swap(z[l],z[i])
            permut(z,l+1,n)
            swap(z[l],z[i])
p=[1,2,3]
t=permut(p,0,3)
print(t)
```

Instead of getting the desirable output I am getting `None`.

Comment: I think you're not returning anything, so variable ```t``` will get ```None``` as function without any return statement returns ```None```

Comment: Since the arguments are immutable (numbers in this case), your `swap` function will not work to swap the values of a, b in place.

Answer (score 0):

Errors with OP code

- Since the arguments are immutable (numbers in this case), swap function will not work to swap the values of a, b in place
- You're not aggregating the permutations found

**Code**

```
def permut(a, k=0, results=None):
    # results array will store the permutations found
    if results is None:
        results = []
    if k == len(a):   # using len(a) means we don't need the argument n in OP code
      results.append(a[:])
    else:
      for i in range(k, len(a)):
         a[k], a[i] = a[i] ,a[k]  # swap values
         permut(a, k+1, results)
         a[k], a[i] = a[i], a[k]  # swap back
    return results
```

**Test**

```
p = [1,2,3]
t = permut(p)   # using default k = 0
print(t)
```

**Output**

```
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 2], [2, 1, 3], [2, 3, 1], [3, 2, 1], [3, 1, 2]]
```